# Atom editor: snippet for inserting a timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, coffeescript, code-snippets, atom-editor

Below is an Atom snippet I was playing with.  What I want to do is insert a timestamp with a developer's name at the end.  This is useful when multiple folks are working on the same codebase and you need to comment out some code or add a comment.  This way other developers know who did what, and when they did it.  I've found it very useful and wanted to create a snippet to do this.

However, as you can see from the snippet, it's very ugly...JS is not my forte.  Is there a clean way to do this?

`time` => tab => `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM / NAME`

```
'.source':
  'Timestamp':
    'prefix': 'time'
    'body': """
      # #{datetime = new Date(); datetime.getFullYear()}-#{(datetime.getMonth()+1)}-#{datetime.getDate()} #{datetime.getHours()}:#{datetime.getMinutes()} / NAME
    """
```

Comment: you might want to use something like moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get to this without resorting to a library like moment.js or Date.js is by using [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

This will print the date like this:

```
2014-09-05T07:15:14.840Z
```

The downside is that this will always print the date in UTC.

Some more options are listed here: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date) - maybe you'll see something there. Based on a quick glance of the answers, what you're doing looks pretty good actually.

Answer (score -3):

For using `momentjs` here is minimal example of a snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/a0m9s3rc/

**HTML & JavaScript** - (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <body>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function (name) {
                var date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'),
                    name = name || '< Developer Name >',
                    string = date + ' / ' + name;
                return console.log(string);
            })('Dan L');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This outputs into the browser's `console`:

```
2014-09-05 15:09 / Dan L
```

Note: This currently outputs to the browser's F12 developer tool's console using `console.log`, which you could change to output to the page with `document.write` in the `return` statement instead.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the requested feature. OP asks for a snippet to insert the timestamp in the Atom editor. Not as Javascript (in an HTML page or whatever).